# MongoDB cloning (db.copyDatabase), clone only half of database

Tags: mongodb

I have database which have about 4 GB data and when I try dump it by mongodump then it dump only something about 1,93 GB. And when I try to clone it by `db.copyDatabase()` then it copy same amount of data as mongodump.

Is there some limit in MongoDb?

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad english (I hope that you will understand me).

**EDIT**

```
{
        "ns" : "some-db.persons",
        "firstExtent" : "0:31000 ns:some-db.persons",
        "lastExtent" : "4:b50d000 ns:some-db.persons",
        "extentCount" : 13,
        "extents" : [
                {
                        "loc" : "0:31000",
                        "xnext" : "0:42000",
                        "xprev" : "null",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 32768,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:310b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:38e3c"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:42000",
                        "xnext" : "0:62000",
                        "xprev" : "0:31000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 131072,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:420b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:61e64"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:62000",
                        "xnext" : "0:e2000",
                        "xprev" : "0:42000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 524288,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:620b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:e0f0c"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:e2000",
                        "xnext" : "0:372000",
                        "xprev" : "0:62000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 2097152,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:e20b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:2e1d94"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:372000",
                        "xnext" : "0:dd6000",
                        "xprev" : "0:e2000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 8388608,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:3720b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:b71e80"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:dd6000",
                        "xnext" : "0:2233000",
                        "xprev" : "0:372000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 11325440,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:dd60b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:18a2db8"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "0:2233000",
                        "xnext" : "1:2000",
                        "xprev" : "0:dd6000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 15290368,
                        "firstRecord" : "0:22330b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "0:30c7e20"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "1:2000",
                        "xnext" : "1:223d000",
                        "xprev" : "0:2233000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 20643840,
                        "firstRecord" : "1:20b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "1:13b1e9c"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "1:223d000",
                        "xnext" : "2:2000",
                        "xprev" : "1:2000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 27869184,
                        "firstRecord" : "1:223d0b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "1:3cd0e7c"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "2:2000",
                        "xnext" : "2:73ba000",
                        "xprev" : "1:223d000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 37625856,
                        "firstRecord" : "2:20b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "2:23e3dd8"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "2:73ba000",
                        "xnext" : "3:4bd7000",
                        "xprev" : "2:2000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 50798592,
                        "firstRecord" : "2:73ba0b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "2:a42be78"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "3:4bd7000",
                        "xnext" : "4:b50d000",
                        "xprev" : "2:73ba000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 68579328,
                        "firstRecord" : "3:4bd70b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "3:8d3dda4"
                },
                {
                        "loc" : "4:b50d000",
                        "xnext" : "null",
                        "xprev" : "3:4bd7000",
                        "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                        "size" : 92581888,
                        "firstRecord" : "4:b50d0b0",
                        "lastRecord" : "4:ba17118"
                }
        ],
        "datasize" : 244286608,
        "nrecords" : 268872,
        "lastExtentSize" : 92581888,
        "padding" : 1,
        "firstExtentDetails" : {
                "loc" : "0:31000",
                "xnext" : "0:42000",
                "xprev" : "null",
                "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                "size" : 32768,
                "firstRecord" : "0:310b0",
                "lastRecord" : "0:38e3c"
        },
        "lastExtentDetails" : {
                "loc" : "4:b50d000",
                "xnext" : "null",
                "xprev" : "3:4bd7000",
                "nsdiag" : "some-db.persons",
                "size" : 92581888,
                "firstRecord" : "4:b50d0b0",
                "lastRecord" : "4:ba17118"
        },
        "objectsFound" : 218678,
        "invalidObjects" : 0,
        "bytesWithHeaders" : 207046812,
        "bytesWithoutHeaders" : 203547964,
        "deletedCount" : 6,
        "deletedSize" : 87297536,
        "nIndexes" : 1,
        "keysPerIndex" : {
                "some-db.persons.$_id_" : 268872
        },
        "valid" : true,
        "errors" : [ ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data's likely all there; MongoDB allocates extra space over time that wouldn't be included in a copy.  Check the doc counts in the collections to verify.

Comment: Ok, I checked it. First collection what I have is full with 96279 docs and second collection only with 70596 docs of 268872 docs. I have idea, that I will try to copy just the second collection.

Comment: @user1607808 Hmm...did you validate the source collections to check them for issues?  `db.mycoll.validate()` or `db.mycoll.validate({full:true})`

Comment: @JohnyHK I checked that and I never see that output. But there were no errors and It's saying, that it is valid (When you need some more data I will copy the output to my first post).

Comment: you need to do db.printCollectionStats() in the source db and then in the target db after and compare.  Once you have more information about which collections may have documents missing it may be easier to suggest how to verify what happened.